# How to check if there exists a field across all objects with specific label

Tags: custom-field, metadata-api, metadata, fields, label

I have label text of field. I need to search if there exists a custom field with that label across objects. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use describes to get this information. It will be agonizingly slow but it will work.

```
public static Set<SObjectType> getTypesWithFieldLabel(String label)
{
    Set<SObjectType> types = new Set<SObjectType>();
    for (SObjectType sObjectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
    {
        for (SObjectField field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
        {
            if (label == field.getDescribe().getLabel())
            {
                types.add(sObjectType);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return types;
}
```